# Spark executor lost because of GC overhead limit exceeded even though using 20 executors using 25GB each

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This GC overhead limit error is making me crazy. I have 20 executors using 25 GB each I dont understand at all how can it throw GC overhead I also dont that that big datasets. Once this GC error occurs in executor it will get lost and slowly other executors getting lost because of IOException, Rpc client disassociated, shuffle not found etc.

I am new to Spark.

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 363.0 (TID 3373, myhost.com): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            at org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String.toString(UTF8String.scala:150)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getString(rows.scala:120)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.STRING$.actualSize(ColumnType.scala:312)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.compression.DictionaryEncoding$Encoder.gatherCompressibilityStats(compressionSchemes.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.gatherCompressibilityStats(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:72)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.appendFrom(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:80)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.appendFrom(ColumnBuilder.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:148)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$3$$anon$1.next(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:124)
            at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
            at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GC overhead limit exceeded is thrown when the cpu spends more than 98% for garbage collection tasks. It happens in Scala when using immutable data structures since that for each transformation the JVM will have to re-create a lot of new objects and remove the previous ones from the heap. So if this is your problem, try to use some mutable data structures instead.

Please read this page http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning to learn how to tune your GC.